# Naming of method-local constants in checkstyle

Tags: java, constants, checkstyle

How should java method-local constants be named?

If a constant is used only used in the context of a method, it should be declared inside the method (as a `final` variable). But what syntax should be used? For me, the most readable way is to use `ALL_CAPS`, but checkstyle seems to disagree:

```
int compute(int n) {
    final int FACTOR = 27;
    return FACTOR * n;
}
```

will produce the checkstyle warning:

```
Name 'FACTOR' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'.
```

See also: [What are your thoughts on method scoped constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244191/what-are-your-thoughts-on-method-scoped-constants)

Comment: It's a constant. Why would you want to allocate memory and initialize a variable every time the method is called? Define it as a constant, outside of the method.

Comment: @JB Nizet: http://stackoverflow.com/a/244315/319621

Comment: If you agree with that, then also realize that you're not defining a constant, but a variable. And variables are written in lowercase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Google Java Style](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.2.7-local-variable-names), the currently popular style guide, says:

> Local variable names are written in lowerCamelCase  [...] *Even when final and immutable*, local variables are not considered to be constants, and should not be styled as constants.

This is also the convention assumed by Checkstyle's *LocalFinalVariableName* check.

Answer (score 2):

> Constants - The names of variables declared class constants and of
>   ANSI constants should be all uppercase with words separated by
>   underscores ("_"). (ANSI constants should be avoided, for ease of
>   debugging.)

Source: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Like this:

```
final int FACTOR = 27;
int compute(int n) {
    return FACTOR*n;
}
```

Noticed that since it's a constant field, I moved it outside the method.

**EDIT 2:**

When having a final variable inside a method, you're suppose to follow the code convention of the local variable which is:

> Variables - Except for variables, all instance, class, and class constants are in
>   mixed case with a lowercase first letter. Internal words start with
>   capital letters. Variable names should not start with underscore _ or
>   dollar sign $ characters, even though both are allowed.
>
> Variable names should be short yet meaningful. The choice of a
>   variable name should be mnemonic- that is, designed to indicate to the
>   casual observer the intent of its use. One-character variable names
>   should be avoided except for temporary "throwaway" variables. Common
>   names for temporary variables are i, j, k, m, and n for integers; c,
>   d, and e for characters.

Thus the checkstyle warning.

Comment: @gatinueta, it doesn't really depend on what you like and what you don't. I believe you should consider every factor possible. Would this `final` variable be used by other methods? Would other class want to know about this? Read the other answers. It's pretty good. BTW, I changed my answer.

Comment: Right, it doesn't matter what I like, I should elaborate: I prefer a locally declared final to a class constant if the value is only used within the method and there also no other reason it should be visible outside this method.

Answer (score 0):

all the local variable name should be in small letter.

```
int compute(int n) {
final int factor= 27;
return factor*n;
```

}

and if its a constant define it in outside your method and name it in ALL_CAPS

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the uppercase notation is used only for public "constants" since they build part of the API of your class or library.

If you make it a method-local variable, then the normal notation for variables applies. It just "happens" to be final.